# Use one Macro for multiple instances

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to use Excel VBA to control text box background colors depending on the values in certain cells. Each text box corresponds to a different cell with a value in it. I have about 60 text boxes to control and 4 possible colors for each one. Using switch statements, I would basically have to do 4 cases for each of the 60 text boxes... Assuming I use the way I have it set up now as seen below:

```
Select Case Cells(50, 2).Value
        Case Is = 1, 6, 11, 16
            .TextBox13.BackColor = RGB(0, 255, 0)
        Case Is = 5
            .TextBox13.BackColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        Case Is = 0
            .TextBox13.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        Case Is = 10, 15
            .TextBox13.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 0)
    End Select
```

And so on for all 60. However, the value range is always the same, and the colors correspond with the same values for each one. I'm assuming there must be a way to build one module to actually set the colors, and just use switch statements to determine with cell to send to that module?

EDIT: I've attached a screenshot of the workspace so you can see what I'm going for

[image: screenshot]

Comment: So all the text boxes should be the same color?  Are they all on the same worksheet?

Comment: Are you talking about textboxes on UserForm?

Comment: Yes, same worksheet, and no they won't always be the same color. For example, values 10 and 15 will always make the box yellow. However, while one value is 10, another one may be 6 which would be green. (It is active X text box)

Answer (score 0):

Some piece of your code is wrong. It's `Select Case ... End Select`

```
Select Case Cells(50, 2).Value
    Case 1, 6, 11, 16
        tbxObject.BackColor = RGB(0, 255, 0)
    Case 5
        tbxObject.BackColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    Case 0
        tbxObject.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    Case 10, 15
        tbxObject.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 0)
End Select
```

Please, see: [Select ... Case statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy37t14y.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

If some piece of code is used several times, you have to move it into single general soubroutine, which can accept `TextBox` object as input parameter.

```
Sub ColorMyTextBox(wsh As Worksheet, sTextBoxName As String)
   Dim txtObject As OleObject

   Set txtObject = wsh.OleObjects(sTextBoxName)
   If TypeName(txtObject) <> "TextBox" Then Goto Exit_Sub

  'here Select Case statement

Exit_Sub:

End Sub
```

Got it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so if I use that, how will I specify the cell numbers to use in the case statements? It won't always be cells(50,2)... And I also get errors when sending the worksheet name